# Python requests get 401 after successful login

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from a website which requires to login. I try to get python requests Session and I am able to login using post. But after successful login the second request (get) I make gets me a 401. Interesting thing is the same code works on one host but not the other. The hosts are identical. Does anyone know what could be the issue? Below is the code snippet from my python that I have written. I am using python 2.7 and requests version 2.0.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (self.userName, self.password)
session.proxies = self.proxyInformation   # {'http' : http://<zyz>, 'https' : https://xyz}

response = session.post(self.url)
print "response = ", response.status_code   # Gets 200
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

boxResponse = soup.find('div', attrs= {'class' : 'boxContent'})

for data in boxResponse.select("p a"):
    hrefLink = data['href']
    if hrefLink is None:
        continue

    print "hrefLink = ", hrefLink
    print self._NAME, " : Processing {0}".format(hrefLink)

    dataResponse = session.get(hrefLink)
    print "dataResponse = ", dataResponse    # Gets 401
```

Comment: What URLs are being accessed in `session.get()`? Are they on the same host, or are they elsewhere, possibly requiring different login credentials?

Comment: Yes they are on the same host.

Comment: I suspect that there's a cookie being set on the first response. Since you're setting auth on the session, requests re-sends it with the cookie and the server might reject that as a valid request.